# Show that $\sum \frac{\mu(n) \ln(n)}{n}=-1$

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function

I am thinking of interpreting this as $-\frac{d}{ds}(\frac{1}{\zeta(s)})$ evaluated at $s=1$, or connecting it with $\Lambda$, but not exactly sure how to.

Any reference/textbook to look at for such series properties, especially those that might connect to involutions, of NT functions ($\mu,\ \Lambda,\ \sigma,\ \varphi,$ etc.) with proofs is also appreciated!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255262/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-mun-frac-log-nn-1

Comment: Ah, Thank you! @KCd

Comment: If the series converges then it does it to $-\frac{d}{ds}(\frac{1}{\zeta(s)})$ evaluated at $1$. 

It is highly non-trivial to prove that it converges. The convergence is a consequence of the PNT.